# How Node.js implements require() in its own internals?

Tags: node.js

While going through the source of `require()` in the GitHub repository for Node.js, I am surprised and confused by one thing:

The file [loader.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js) that actually defines the `require()` logic, uses `require()` calls in itself.

How is this possible?

Is there some other code for the `require()` calls used in the internals of Node.js, for e.g. all the `require()` calls used in loader.js file.

I know that all `require()` calls in a Node.js program that I write in a given editor, on my machine, are resolved using the `Module.prototype.require` method declared in loader.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the actual base `require` is defined [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/bootstrap/loaders.js), in `/internal/bootstrap/loaders.js`. [This line](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/46e6c649ec0ba80df409cfaad41858807d52e760/lib/internal/bootstrap/loaders.js#L311) makes use of [`compileFunction][3]` in `/lib/vm.js`. That again uses `_compileFunction` which is defined as such:

```js
const {
  ContextifyScript,
  MicrotaskQueue,
  makeContext,
  isContext: _isContext,
  constants,
  compileFunction: _compileFunction,
  measureMemory: _measureMemory,
} = internalBinding('contextify');
```

Which, if we go back to `/internal/bootstrap/loaders.js`, is defined as such:

```js
let internalBinding;
{
  const bindingObj = ObjectCreate(null);
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-global-assign
  internalBinding = function internalBinding(module) {
    let mod = bindingObj[module];
    if (typeof mod !== 'object') {
      mod = bindingObj[module] = getInternalBinding(module);
      ArrayPrototypePush(moduleLoadList, `Internal Binding ${module}`);
    }
    return mod;
  };
}
```

And `getInternalBinding` we find at the top of that file, in this comment:

```js
// This file is compiled as if it's wrapped in a function with arguments
// passed by node::RunBootstrapping()
/* global process, getLinkedBinding, getInternalBinding, primordials */
```

Which brings an end to our tour here. So yes, there's still some code between the `require()` defined in `loader.js` and the actual C binding. As for what happens in C-land, I'm not sure myself.

Comment: I wonder then what's the purpose of creating a new `require()` function, when there already is one defined?

Comment: Is the new `require()`, defined in loader.js, a bit more flexible than the one defined in the file node.js? If yes, then how?

Comment: Yes. The one in `loaders.js` seems only capable of requiring native modules. The one in `loader.js` actually sets up the whole deal of loading (non-native) modules from files, load modules relative to the current module, wrap module code in the `(function (exports, require, ...)` wrapper (therefore providing it its own `require` that's relative to the module's path), ...

Comment: Any ideas why the Node team didn't implement it just once as a full-fledge function, rather than first create a minimal function and then a more robust function?

Comment: Not sure, but I'd say they use layering both for maintenance and clarity. You have `getInternalBinding`, on top of that `loaders.js` which wraps requiring native modules using bindings, then `loader.js` which _actually_ implements the whole CJS module/require system. Mind that we're talking about `/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js`. Mind that there's also [`/internal/modules/esm/loader.js`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/modules/esm/loader.js) for ESM modules.

Comment: Just one more thing, because I am not that familiar with C++ and low-level ideas such as binaries. It's stated in the `loaders.js` file, you linked to, that all core node modules are compiled into node binaries to improve performance. Can you please just extend on what exactly does this mean *in terms of requiring modules*?

Comment: Honestly, I don't actually know. I'd assume that e.g. the `fs` module is written (and "executed") in C, where `fileWriteSync` etc are exposed bindings to C functions. Requiring the module is basically requiring (a JS wrapper of) this C-hosted module. But again, don't actually know.